# Limiting Target to a Range of Noncontiguous Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have formatted a worksheet that allows me to:

- Double-click on a blank cell and the background color turns to red and gives it a value of "Not Recvd".
- Double-click it again and it turns orange with a "Partial" value.
- Double-click it again and it turns green with a "Recvd" value.
- Double-click it again and it turns blue with a "NA" value.
- Double-click it again and it goes back to blank.

I was able to accomplish this with the help of tutorials and online searches. I want to add a couple more features to the spreadsheet but haven't been able to find/figure these out. The features that need to be inserted into existing code are:

1. Assigning a specific cell/range (as opposed to every cell on worksheet) the ability of changing color/value with a double-click as described above. There are 120 cells I need to designate as such.
2. Assuming that none of the cells are blank, I need to insert an equation that calculates what percentage of the 120 cells that are not blue/"NA" are red/"Not Recvd"; are orange/"Partial"; and are green/"Recvd". These percentages would to be located on the same worksheet and I would like to know how to designate specific cells/range for that as well.

I would like it to look something like this:

```
Not Recvd  15%
Partial    20%
Recvd      65%
```

Here is the existing code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        Target.Value = " "
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Target.Value = "Not Recvd"
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        Target.Value = "Partial"
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45 Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Target.Value = "Recvd"
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 41
        Target.Value = "N/A"
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 41 Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Value = " "
    End If

    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I am using Windows XP and Excel 2003.

Comment: Do all 120 cells have blank values initially?

Comment: It would help to know what the worksheet cell address of the *'120 cells'* is/was and where you wanted the percentages.

Comment: Yes, all 120 cells have blank cells initially.  Once I have received documents/information from a request  then I would double-click cells to reflect status (Not Recvd; Partial; Recvd: N/A) of certain document/information (rows) in that category (columns).   The cell addresses are

Comment: The cell addresses are: H6:H7,H10:H12,H15:H17,H20:H24,H27,H30,H33,H36,H39,H42,H45,H48,H51,H54,H57,K6:K7,K10:K12,K15:K17,K20:K24,K27,K30,K33,K36,K39,K42,K45,K48,K51,K54,K57,N6:N7,N10:N12,N15:N17,N20:N24,N27,N30,N33,N36,N39,N42,45,48,N51,N54,N57,Q6:Q7,Q10:Q12,Q15:Q17,Q20:Q24,Q27,Q30,Q33,Q36,Q39,Q42,Q45,Q48,Q51,Q54,Q57,T6:T7,T10:T12,T15:T17,T20:T24,T27,T30,T33,T36,T39,42,T45,T48,T51,T54,57,W6:W7,W10:W12,W15:W17,W20:W24,W27,W30,W33,W36,W39,W42,45,W48,W51,W54,W57.

Comment: The percentages would be located at AA22,AA23,AA24.

Comment: Yes, all 120 cells have blank cells initially. Once I have received documents/information from a request then I would double-click cells to reflect status (Not Recvd; Partial; Recvd: N/A) of certain document/information (rows) in that category (columns).  @rusk

Comment: The cell addresses are: H6:H7,H10:H12,H15:H17,H20:H24,H27,H30,H33,H36,H39,H42,H45,H48,H51,H54,H57,K6:K7,‌K10:K12,K15:K17,K20:K24,K27,K30,K33,K36,K39,K42,K45,K48,K51,K54,K57,N6:N7,N10:N12‌,N15:N17,N20:N24,N27,N30,N33,N36,N39,N42,45,48,N51,N54,N57,Q6:Q7,Q10:Q12,Q15:Q17,‌Q20:Q24,Q27,Q30,Q33,Q36,Q39,Q42,Q45,Q48,Q51,Q54,Q57,T6:T7,T10:T12,T15:T17,T20:T24‌,T27,T30,T33,T36,T39,42,T45,T48,T51,T54,57,W6:W7,W10:W12,W15:W17,W20:W24,W27,W30,‌W33,W36,W39,W42,45,W48,W51,W54,W57.   
The percentages would be located at AA22,AA23,AA24.  @Jeeped

Comment: @rusk  Yes, all 120 cells have blank cells initially. Once I have received documents/information from a request then I would double-click cells to reflect status (Not Recvd; Partial; Recvd: N/A) of certain document/information (rows) in that category (columns).  Sorry for re-sends but new at this.

Comment: @Jeeped 
The cell addresses are: H6:H7,H10:H12,H15:H17,H20:H24,H27,H30,H33,H36,H39,H42,H45,H48,H51,H54,H57,K6:K7,‌​‌K10:K12,K15:K17,K20:K24,K27,K30,K33,K36,K39,K42,K45,K48,K51,K54,K57,N6:N7,N10:N1‌2‌,N15:N17,N20:N24,N27,N30,N33,N36,N39,N42,45,48,N51,N54,N57,Q6:Q7,Q10:Q12,Q15:Q1‌7,‌Q20:Q24,Q27,Q30,Q33,Q36,Q39,Q42,Q45,Q48,Q51,Q54,Q57,T6:T7,T10:T12,T15:T17,T20:‌T24‌,T27,T30,T33,T36,T39,42,T45,T48,T51,T54,57,W6:W7,W10:W12,W15:W17,W20:W24,W27,‌W30,‌W33,W36,W39,W42,45,W48,W51,W54,W57. The percentages would be located at AA22,AA23,AA24.  Sorry for resends but new at this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to repair a few typos in your cell range but I identified its repeating pattern and broke it into two strings referencing the rows and columns. I put this into the *Declarations* area (top of the worksheet code sheet) as private constant strings.

```
Private Const pcISECcols As String = "H:H,K:K,N:N,Q:Q,T:T,W:W"
Private Const pcISECrows As String = "6:7,10:12,15:17,20:24,27:27,30:30,33:33,36:36,39:39,42:42,45:45,48:48,51:51,54:54,57:57"
```

These will be used to define range objects within an `Intersect` ([Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772)) call to see if your double-clicked cell should be included. When I ran  `Intersect(Range(pcISECcols), Range(pcISECrows)).Interior.ColorIndex = 10` I came up with this.

[image: Intersect(target, rows, columns)]

While that actually comes up as 144 cells instead of 120, it is my best guess from what you have provided so all that needs to be done would be to add the cell you are double-clicking to the intersect function to achieve a dc-filtered response.

While I found there was some ambiguity with your description of *'percentages would be located at AA22,AA23,AA24'*, I have assumed that the percentages were intended to be in AA22:AA24 and the legend descriptions identifying each percentage were intended for Z22:Z24.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const pcISECcols As String = "H:H,K:K,N:N,Q:Q,T:T,W:W"
Private Const pcISECrows As String = "6:7,10:12,15:17,20:24,27:27,30:30,33:33,36:36,39:39,42:42,45:45,48:48,51:51,54:54,57:57"

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(pcISECcols), Range(pcISECrows)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim iCNT As Long, rPCT As Range
        'Debug.Print Intersect(Range(pcISECcols), Range(pcISECrows)).Count
        'Debug.Print Intersect(Range(pcISECcols), Range(pcISECrows)).Address
        Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
            Case xlNone
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Target.Value = "Not Recvd"
            Case 3
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                Target.Value = "Partial"
            Case 45
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Target.Value = "Recvd"
            Case 4
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 41
                Target.Value = "N/A"
            Case 41
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Target.Value = vbNullString
            Case Else
                Target.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                Target.Value = vbNullString
        End Select

        Range("AA22:AA24") = 0
        With Intersect(Range(pcISECcols), Range(pcISECrows))
            iCNT = .Count
            Debug.Print iCNT
            For Each rPCT In .Cells
                Select Case rPCT.Interior.ColorIndex
                    Case 3
                        Range("AA22") = Range("AA22").Value2 + 1
                    Case 45
                        Range("AA23") = Range("AA23").Value2 + 1
                    Case 4
                        Range("AA24") = Range("AA24").Value2 + 1
                    Case 41
                        iCNT = iCNT - 1
                    Case Else
                        'do nothing
                End Select
            Next rPCT
            Debug.Print iCNT
            Range("AA22") = Range("AA22").Value2 / iCNT
            Range("AA23") = Range("AA23").Value2 / iCNT
            Range("AA24") = Range("AA24").Value2 / iCNT
        End With
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That should be all of it. The count of the cells in the noncontiguous range is decremented for each blue cell and the percentage is retrieved using that count as opposed to all of the cells.

If you wish to use an actual worksheet function for the wider percentages, you can actually use create a `COUNTIF` formula on the whole noncontiguous range. Using a discontinuous range for a `COUNTIF` is difficult but not impossible. The formula for AA2 would be,

```
    =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"H6:H7","H10:H12","H15:H17","H20:H24","H27","H30","H33","H36","H39","H42","H45","H48","H51","H54","H57","K6:K7","K10:K12","K15:K17","K20:K24","K27","K30","K33","K36","K39","K42","K45","K48","K51","K54","K57","Q6:Q7","Q10:Q12","Q15:Q17","Q20:Q24","Q27","Q30","Q33","Q36","Q39","Q42","Q45","Q48","Q51","Q54","Q57","N6:N7","N10:N12","N15:N17","N20:N24","N27","N30","N33","N36","N39","N42","N45","N48","N51","N54","N57","T6:T7","T10:T12","T15:T17","T20:T24","T27","T30","T33","T36","T39","T42","T45","T48","T51","T54","T57","W6:W7","W10:W12","W15:W17","W20:W24","W27","W30","W33","W36","W39","W42","W45","W48","W51","W54","W57"}), Z22))/144
```

Format as a percentage and fill down to AA24.

Comment: You are right, there are 144 cells and you assumed correctly in regards to the locations of percentages and legend descriptions. Thank you. We are not quite all the way there yet. I need to re-phrase my request that calculates percentages. Although all cells are initially blank, as soon as I receive a first volley of input from a 3rd party I would double-click all cells to reflect the status (Red, Orange, Green or Blue) of that initial input. So what I need, is not a % of 144 cells that red, orange or green, but what % of any cells that are not blue that are red, orange or green.

Comment: @Gabe747 - I believe that decrementing the count was the answer to tighten up the percentages. See my modification above,